# Java Rest webservice with bad queryparam

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have the below web service method,

```
@GET
@Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
@Path("/service/salesorder/{identifier}/{orderType}")
public Response readOrder(@PathParam("identifier") String identifier,
                          @PathParam("orderType") String orderType);
```

If user calls the below correct url, i want the service to work fine, if any one calls with bad url (extra query param), which is not defined in the method, i want to throw some error, how can i catch all the bad urls?

Correct URL : http://myApp.com/service/salesorder/123/ShoppingOrder

Bad URL : http://myApp.com/service/salesorder/123/ShoppingOrder&badparam

Comment: That `/service/salesorder/123/ShoppingOrder&badparam` is not a valid path. What HTTP status do you get for it?

Answer (score 1):

Addionial you should inject a @Context method parameter:

```
public Response readOrder(@PathParam("identifier") String identifier,
                          @PathParam("orderType") String orderType,
                          @Context HttpServletRequest req);
```

and then check with the servlet API HttpServletRequest#getParameterNames() if any query parameter is given.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different `@PathParam` value.

```
@Path("/service/salesorder/{identifier}/{orderType:[^&]*}")
```

This would result in a `404 Not Found` for `/service/salesorder/service/salesorder/foo/bar&baz` sind `{orderType:[^&]*}` does not match `ShoppingOrder&badparam`.